# Jsf redirect to new window

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, new-window

i'm making a JSF2.0 project using mojarra primefaces tomcat6.x.

I made a select list and when i select item of the list i want to redirect to the selected url. It can be an internal URL.

It's work but i want to know if it's possible to redirect in new window.

I have the following code JSF:

```
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu onchange="this.form.submit();" valueChangeListener="#{wagent.selectBusinessTravelLink}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['form.select.defaultValue']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{wagent.businessTravelLinks}" var="bLinkItem" itemLabel="#{bLinkItem.label}" itemValue="#{bLinkItem.id}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
```

Java:

```
   public void selectBusinessTravelLink(ValueChangeEvent event) {
// some stuff
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(targetUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript's [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) function rather than `form.submit()` during the `change` event.

Assuming that the select item values are fullworthy URL's, here's an example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Comment: I forgive to clarify, i have external and internal url on my list and i want to open in new window only for external url.

Comment: That get tricky. I'd just do the URL determining job in a JS function instead. If external, do `window.open(url);`. If internal, do `window.location=url;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" (or in your case in onchange), i.e.,

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectOneMenu onchange="this.form.target='_blank'; this.form.submit();" valueChangeListener="#{wagent.selectBusinessTravelLink}">
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['form.select.defaultValue']}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{wagent.businessTravelLinks}" var="bLinkItem" itemLabel="#{bLinkItem.label}" itemValue="#{bLinkItem.id}" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
 </h:form>
```

And of course, don't forget to fix the id attribute in `<h:form id="form">`